# Create a BOOL column based on conditions in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, boolean

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I would like to create another BOOL column or YES/NO column based on the sum of column A and B > 150

I am trying a generator kind of solution:

```
df['Truth'] = ['Yes' for  i in df.columns.values if (df.A+df.B > 150)]
```

I know this does not work but I keep getting another error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do I code this and what does this error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to get a column of Boolean values:

- `(df.A + df.B) > 150` generates a `pandas.Series` of Boolean values. Assign it to a column name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# create the Boolean column
df['Truth'] = (df.A + df.B) > 150

# display(df)
     A   B   C   D  Truth
0   40  15  72  22  False
1   43  82  75   7  False
2   34  49  95  75  False
3   85  47  63  31  False
4   90  20  37  39  False
5   67   4  42  51  False
6   38  33  58  67  False
7   69  88  68  46   True
8   70  95  83  31   True
9   66  80  52  76  False
10  50   4  90  63  False
11  79  49  39  46  False
12   8  50  15   8  False
13  17  22  73  57  False
14  90  62  83  96   True
```

### *What does this error mean*:

- What is shown in the question is a list-comprehension, not a generator.
- `(df.A + df.B)` returns a `pandas.Series`, which can be compared to a value like `150`

  - The issue with the list comprehension is `if (df.A+df.B > 150)`, which causes the `ValueError` because there is a series, not just a single Boolean.
- Another issue is `df.columns.values` is just a list of the column names.
- See [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951) for further details on the error.